# Enable "Allow less secure apps" programmatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

Is there a to enable "Allow less secure apps" for domain users using Google Apps Script? I browsed the G Suite Admin SDK reference but couldn't find anything. There's ResolvedAppAccessSettings: ListTrustedApps in Directory API > Security, but it's not what I wanted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is none. You can check this [FAQ Allow or disallow less secure apps to access accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en) and there is no mention of programatically way of doing this.

However, you may try to check the workaround in this [google forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-apps-manager/vV63aoBrnLY) if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This might not answer fully but Just to let everybody know that less secure apps module (https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/lesssecureapps) is deprecated.

A new option - apppasswords is available to get authentication done via following link.
https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/apppasswords

Use 16 digit code provided by google instead of password and that should be it.
[image]

Note: 2-factor authentication needed to be enabled before proceeding.